# In CKEditor Plugin,there is no way to copy the Headings in Copy Formatting

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor Plugin,there is no way to copy the Headings in Copy Formatting.I need to Copy the Headings in CKEditor Plugin.Please tell the Correct code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [documentation for Copy Formatting](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_copyformatting.html) where it says:

> Copy Formatting only works with inline styles, so it will not copy or apply block-level styles (e.g. headers) to text.

You would probably need to write your own version of Copy Formatting to get the result you want.

Comment: Thank You Man.is it Possible to change that one with Configuration..I need to copy the Headings with copy formatting..What will do for that?

Comment: I believe you would need to extend Copy Formatting with a lot of custom code and this is not a matter of simply changing some configuration setting. I haven’t heard of any similar plugin and the only thing I can recommend is that you check out https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all add-ons repository. Perhaps you will find plugin you want there.